# Uploading file not woking in iphone phonegap but working fine in android

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm facing a big problem of uploading  file in ios phonegap,but the same is working for android .When i upload file from iphone ,it gives me response of 200 i.e. success and bytes that sent.But sever response is target missing ,this means that file is not receiving at server and please provide me any solution as well as possible. Because unable to achieve dead line of project.
Thanks.I'm going to share my code here.

```
 function upload_demo() {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
                                    uploadPhoto1,
                                    function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                                    {
                                    quality         : 50,
                                    destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                    sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                                    }
                                    );
    }

    function uploadPhoto1(imageURI) {
        alert(imageURI);
        alert(activefolder);
        var url="https://server.com/****";
        alert(url);
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
        var headers = {
                    "Authorization" : auth
                };
                options.headers = headers;
                var params = {};
                params.target = activefolder;
                options.params = params;
        options.httpMethod="POST";
        alert(JSON.stringify(options));

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(url), win1, fail1, options,true);
    }

    function win1(r) {
        alert("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        alert("Response = " + r.response);
        alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail1(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below link if helpfull:-

```
http://www.zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap 

options.chunkedMode = false;
```

and instead of this check your plist containing all the permissions